# Swift-Scale SKAction not working

Tags: swift, xcode, scaling, skspritenode, skaction

I'm having some trouble figuring out why my sprites aren't scaling in Swift 3 and Xcode 8. I have 3 identical sprites, ball1, ball2 and ball3, all in the centre of my GameScene.sks and fully visible when the game is run. Here's the relevant code;

```
var ball1 = SKSpriteNode()
var ball2 = SKSpriteNode()
var ball3 = SKSpriteNode()
var signature = Double()
var scaleFactor = Double()
var score = Double()
let signatureOptions = [1, -1]

ball1 = self.childNode(withName: "ball1") as! SKSpriteNode
ball2 = self.childNode(withName: "ball2") as! SKSpriteNode
ball3 = self.childNode(withName: "ball3") as! SKSpriteNode

func myFunction() {
    ball1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    ball2.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    ball3.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    signature = Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Double(signatureOptions.count))))
    scaleFactor = 35 / (0.5 + (score / 20))
    let scaleBall2 = SKAction.scale(by: CGFloat(((100 + scaleFactor) * signature) / 100), duration: 1)
    let scaleBall3 = SKAction.scale(by: CGFloat((((100 + scaleFactor) * signature) / 100) * -1), duration: 1)
    ball2.run(scaleBall2)
    ball3.run(scaleBall3)
}
myFunction()
```

When run, all the sprite repositioning goes to plan, and they all move to the centre. But after that absolutely nothing happens. Is there a problem with the line where I declare the signature variable, deciding whether they grow or shrink? Because at the moment they're doing neither, so if anyone has any idea as to what needs to be happening that isn't, I'd be very appreciative. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be that your scale actions are just returning a value of 1, thus not scaling at all? without knowing how `score` works, its hard to know exactly what `scaleFactor` will be, on my end. The only other thing i can think of, which should be obvious, is that you need to call `myFunction()` at some point as well in order to get this block to execute, although i'm sure you already know that.

Also - Why is this titled and tagged with rotation, when it's directly related to scaling?

Comment: All good points, thank you. I've fixed the function calling at the end, and the title and tags were a mix-up with some other questions, hopefully all resolved now. Score will always be an integer from 0, so it should be impossible to have a value of 1. Thank you for you for your suggestions though, but that doesn't appear to be my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I know the problem!

For one, `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)` is actually the point in the very top left of your `SKView`. To create the nodes in the center of the screen, you would want to do `CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)` to place the nodes in the center of the screen.

Now, to execute the code, you need to call `myFunction` inside of the `didMove` function (equivalent to `viewDidLoad`) like so:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) 
{
    myFunction()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions again, but they don't appear to have changed anything. Still none of them scale. It's also interesting what you said about the centre of my view, but 0,0 does appear to move my sprites to the centre successfully. I wonder if that was something changed recently in Xcode 8 or otherwise.